# Vue Cypress and Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: vue.js, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cypress

I am currently trying to get my E2E tests running on Gitlab with their CI/CD platform.

My issue at the moment is that I cannot both my dev server and cypress to run at the same time so that the E2E tests can run.

Here is my current `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: node

variables:
  npm_config_cache: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.npm"
  CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/cache/Cypress"

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - .npm
    - cache/Cypress
    - node_modules

stages:
  - setup
  - test

setup:
  stage: setup
  image: cypress/base:10
  script:
    - npm ci
    # check Cypress binary path and cached versions
    # useful to make sure we are not carrying around old versions
    - npx cypress cache path
    - npx cypress cache list

cypress:
  stage: test
  image: cypress/base:10
  script:
    # I need to start a dev server here in the background
    - cypress run --record --key <my_key> --parallel
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - cypress/videos/**/*.mp4
      - cypress/screenshots/**/*.png
    expire_in: 7 day
```

Answer (score 1):

In [Cypress's official GitHub page](https://github.com/cypress-io), there is an [example `.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) for [running Cypress in continuous integration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html).
It uses command `npm run start:ci &` for running dev server in the background.
So, your `.gitlab-ci.yml` might look like this:

```
⋮
cypress:
  image: cypress/base:10
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm run start:ci &      # start the server in the background
    - cypress run --record --key <my_key> --parallel
⋮
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use this utility to start the server, wait for an URL to respond, then run tests and shut down the server https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test